# Sql query for adding all the rows' data except

Tags: sql, hive

I am looking for a query that performs sum operation on the all the rows except one. It will be more clear by the example below..

Suppose i have a company table like this

```
Company_name     Rev      order
  c1             100      1000
  c2             200      2000
  c3             300      1500
```

now the query should insert into a table like the way explained below:

```
 c1(rev)      c1(order)     sum of other(rev)          other(order)
  100          1000        500(sum of c2 and c3)      3500(sum of c2 and c3's order)
```

What would be the query for this kind of scenario?

I was thinking of a query:

```
insert into table_name (c1_rev,c1_order,sum_rev,sum_order) 
select rev, order, sum(rev), sum(order) where Company_name=c1 ....
```

but I got stuck as I can not find the sum of other two using this.

Comment: i'm looking for hive. And yeah there is only three company's name and i want only for company name c1

Comment: Hive query data using sql-based language called HiveQL....so basically I want a SQL-query

Comment: Here is the normal SQL query to do so: [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d71d/9), not sure how to write it in Hive, (note that the only part that is MySQL specific is the escaping '`', and `LIMIt` clause)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server, you could do something like this to fetch the data:

```
WITH totals AS
(SELECT SUM(rev) revSum, SUM(ORDER_) orderSum 
   FROM T)
SELECT company_name, 
       rev, 
       order_, 
       totals.revsum - rev AS otherRev, 
       totals.orderSum - order_ AS otherOrder
FROM  t, totals
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Company_name ,
  Rev ,
  ORDER,
  (SELECT SUM(Rev ) FROM table_name k WHERE k.Company_name<>t.Company_name
  )"sum of other(rev)",
  (SELECT SUM(order ) FROM table_name k WHERE k.Company_name<>t.Company_name
  )"other(order)"
FROM table_name t
```

Answer (score 0):

Having without Group By would be the best solution but HIVE dosen't suport it for now, try this:

```
insert into table table_name 
select rev, order,  sumRev,  sumOrd 
from (
    select Company_name,rev, order, sum(rev)-rev as sumRev, sum(order) - order as sumOrd from base_table 
) a
where Company_name='c1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, a query similar to:

```
select sq.cnn,sum(rev),sum(orders) from 
(select if(cn=='c1','c1','other') as cnn, rev,orders from test_cn) sq
group by sq.cnn;
```

will generate 2 rows :

> ```
> c1      100     1000
> other   500     3500
> ```

Doesn't exactly match your output, but can extract in a form you need.

To test, create a text file with the following:

> ```
> % cat test_cn
> c1|100|1000
> c2|200|2000
> c3|300|3000
> ```

and in hive:

> ```
> hive> drop table if exists test_cn;
> hive> create table test_cn (cn string, rev int, orders int) row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as textfile;
> hive> select sq.cnn,sum(rev),sum(orders) from (select if(cn=='c1','c1','other') as cnn, rev,orders from test_cn)sq group by sq.cnn;
> ```